# Explanation of a solved puzzle' solution

Tags: puzzle

This question pertains to the solution of a puzzle offered some times ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105698/1963).

However, as suggested by the author of the original answer, it might be a good idea to rewrite a more fleshed out version of his answer as it has become difficult to understand the original version.

From the rest of the original answer we know the solution 
 is (23,10,5). We also have a computer code that computes this solution. But there is very little explanation of the logic that lead to this code. Unfortunately, *that* (the reasoning), more than the actual solution, is what I am most interested in.

To put things in context, the puzzle starts like so:

> A few researchers are trying to crack a code which involves
>   discovering the values of three integers. They know they are between 1
>   and 100 (inclusive), and that they may be the same.
>
> They each have a different piece of information;
>
> Alice knows the geometric mean
>
> Bob knows the arithmetic mean
>
> Chris knows the arithmetic mean of the squares
>
> They get together to share information and crack the code, but they
>   are being very secretive in an attempt to conceal their results from
>   anyone else. You listen in to their conversation;
>
> Chris: “I don't know all of the numbers”
>
> Alice: “I don't know any of the numbers”

For Chris the list of candidates is (these all have the same sum of squares):

$$(17, 14, 13), (19, 17, 2), (22, 11, 7), (22, 13, 1), (23, 10, 5), (23, 11, 2), (25, 5, 2)$$

For Alice the list of candidates is (these all have the same geometric mean):

$$(23, 10, 5), (25, 23, 2), (46, 5, 5), (46, 25, 1), (50, 23, 1)$$

Now Chris adds:

> Chris: “You didn't need to tell me that, I knew that already”
>
> Alice: “Well now I know all the numbers!”

My question is: *how does Alice uses this information to exclude the spurious numbers from her list?*

---

So for example, the reason Chris says:

> Chris: “You didn't need to tell me that, I knew that already”

is I believe as follows. Consider for example any element from Chris's list, say $C_1=(17, 14, 13)$. Chris knows that this element has the same fingerprint for Alice as:

$$A(C_1)=\{(17, 14, 13), (26, 17, 7), (34, 13, 7), (91, 17, 2), (91, 34, 1)\}$$

and the intersection of all the members of $A(C_1)$ is empty. This is I think the meaning of Alice's “I don't know any of the numbers”: She can't point to a single number she is sure will be in the solution.

Because this holds for 
 each candidate solution $A(C_1),\ldots,A(C_7)$ in Chris's list, Chris already knows that all of Alice's  candidate solutions 
 must have an empty intersection (which is the meaning, I think, of Chris's "You didn't need to tell me that, I knew that already")

Comment: I'm more interested in how Chris _knew_ that Alice didn't know her code, since for all he knows, the code could be $(23,19,17)$, which would have a unique geometric mean. Is it implied that none of them have been given information that would by itself have a unique solution?

Comment: The question at the original link is all the elements I have, but, yes, I think that we should understand the question to mean that at the beginning, all of them know that none of them knows the correct solution (as you point out, the original solution, which is the one I am trying to understand also assumes this).

Comment: Here is what I imagine it must mean.  For each candidate in Alice's list, e.g. $A_2 = (26,17,7)$, Alice can form the list of elements for Chris which contains $A_2$; in your notation, this would be $C(A_2)$, and she imagines that Chris has the list.  Now if you repeat your above analysis (which you did above for $\left\{C_1, \dots, C_7 \right\}$ to analyze the statement that Chris made), but instead for the list $C(A_2) = \left\{ C(A_2)_1, \dots, C(A_2)_n \right\}$, then probably you will see that the intersection of all the members of each list $A(C(A_2)_i)$ is nonempty.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @MichaelHarrison: The list $C(A_2)$ contains all the elements that have the same sum of squares as $A_2$. These are: $(22, 19, 13), (23, 17, 14), (23, 22, 1), (25, 17, 10), (26, 13, 13), (26, 17, 7), (29, 13, 2), (31, 7, 2)$. Then, I think, $A(C(A_2)_1)$ are all elements for which the geometric mean is the same as $(22, 19, 13)$ (correct?) which are: $(22, 19, 13), (26, 19, 11), (38, 13, 11)$. I must confess, I am not sure I understand after "Then probably..." but FWIW this last list does not intersect with the correct solution.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for computing.  I said something wrong in my last sentence.  I should have said "the intersection of all the members of ATLEAST ONE list $A(C(A_2)_i)$ is nonempty."  Can you check this?  I can try to explain again fully.  Alice thinks: If the numbers are $(26,17,7)$, then Chris' list looks like <the $C(A_2)$ which you wrote>.  Imagine Chris has this list and he is now going through each element $C(A_2)_i$ thinking "what would Alice's list look like if the number is $C(A_2)_i$.  This is your list $A(C(A_2))_i$.  Evidently, since Chris says "I knew that already" means that...

Comment: *he went through every list of that form and noticed that the intersection was empty*  (this is exactly the statement which you say is TRUE about $A(C_1)$ in your original post, and it must be FALSE for every other possible list Chris could have had).  That is, any other $C(A_j)$, $j \neq 1$ should have the property that there exists some $i$ such that $A(C(A_j)_i)$ is a list whose elements have an intersection.

Comment: Your model is correct in the sense that is there is indeed at least one such case. For example: let's take $A_3=(34, 13, 7)$ (this has the same geometric mean as $A_2=(26,17,7)$). Then $C(A_3)_2=(26, 23, 13)$ ( this has the same sum of squares as $A_3=(34, 13, 7)$). Now, $A(C(A_3)_2)=[(26, 23, 13), (46, 13, 13)]$ (these two have the same geometric mean). And the intersection of these two sets is $\{13\}$. So there is at least one list $A(C(A_3)_2)$ for which the intersection of its elements is non empty. In fact I find many such $A(C(A_i)_j)$.

Comment: Thank you again for the computations; nice to see everything worked out.  Just for the purposes of having a rigorous answer (which is neater than this comment thread), I summarized as one complete thought below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closure, this formally summarizes the comments:

Alice has five candidates which we call $A_1, \dots, A_5$.  For each of these candidates $A_i$, she can compute the list $C(A_i)$, which is the list of elements with the same sum of squares as $A_i$.  In Alice's mind, the five lists $C(A_1),\dots,C(A_5)$ are the possible lists which Chris is looking at.

When Chris says "you didn't need to tell me that, I knew that already," he is telling Alice that the list $C(A_{i^*})$ he is looking at has the following property:
$$\mbox{For every } j, \mbox{ the elements of the list } A(C(A_{i^*})_j) \mbox{ have empty intersection}.$$

Thus Alice can deduce the value of $i^*$, because there is only one $i = i^*$ for which the above statement holds.  That is, *for every $i \neq i^*$* the following (negation of the statement above) holds:
$$\mbox{There exists } j \mbox{ such that the elements of the list } A(C(A_{i})_j) \mbox{ have nonempty intersection.}$$

---

Edit by the O.P.: 
I am adding to the answer the result of the computations to illustrate Michael Harrison's answer.

Alice knows that the geometric mean of the correct solution is $1150^{1/3}$. Given this information, she knows the correct solution is one of:

$$A=\{(23, 10, 5),(25, 23, 2),(46, 5, 5),(46, 25, 1),(50, 23, 1)\}$$

Consider the first element in this set. Let us call it $A_1$. The sum of squares of the elements in $A_1$ is 654. If $A_1$ were the correct solution, Chris's list would be:

$$C(A_1)=\{(17, 14, 13), (19, 17, 2), (22, 11, 7), (22, 13, 1), (23, 10, 5), (23, 11, 2), (25, 5, 2)\}$$

The members of $A(C(A_i)_j)$ are all elements that have same geometric mean as $C(A_i)_j$. For $C(A_1)_1$, these are:

$$A(C(A_1)_1)=\{(17, 14, 13), (26, 17, 7), (34, 13, 7), (91, 17, 2), (91, 34, 1)\}$$

As explained in Michael Harrison's answer above, the elements of $A(C(A_1)_1)$ have an empty intersection. The python code from the original answer can be used to show that the same holds for all the $A(C(A_1)_j)$'s (the code to produce these output is placed below this answer):

```
A(C_1)_1): [(17, 14, 13), (26, 17, 7), (34, 13, 7), (91, 17, 2), (91, 34, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_2): [(19, 17, 2), (34, 19, 1), (38, 17, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_3): [(14, 11, 11), (22, 11, 7), (77, 11, 2), (77, 22, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_4): [(13, 11, 2), (22, 13, 1), (26, 11, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_5): [(23, 10, 5), (25, 23, 2), (46, 5, 5), (46, 25, 1), (50, 23, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_6): [(23, 11, 2), (23, 22, 1), (46, 11, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
A(C_1)_7): [(10, 5, 5), (25, 5, 2), (25, 10, 1), (50, 5, 1)]. Empty intersection: True
```

However, as explained in Michael Harrison's answer, the set corresponding to $i=1$ is the only one of Alice's 5 candidate solution for which the corresponding $A(C(A_i)_j)$ have an empty intersection for all $j$'s (the last code below can be easily modified to show that this in indeed the case).

Self contained code from original answer linked in the question:

```
def add_to_hist(hist, what, where):
    if where not in hist:
        hist[where] = []
    hist[where].append(what)

def all_numbers():
    for a in range(1,101):
        for b in range(1,a+1):
            for c in range(1,b+1):
                yield a,b,c

def tally():
    global ALICE, BOB, CHRIS
    ALICE = dict()
    BOB = dict()
    CHRIS = dict()
    for a,b,c in all_numbers():
        add_to_hist(ALICE, (a,b,c), a*b*c)
        add_to_hist(BOB, (a,b,c), a+b+c)
        add_to_hist(CHRIS, (a,b,c), a*a+b*b+c*c)
    ALICE[0] = lambda a,b,c: a*b*c
    BOB[0] = lambda a,b,c: a+b+c
    CHRIS[0] = lambda a,b,c: a*a+b*b+c*c
```

Code to show all members of $A(C(A_1)_j)$:

```
tally()
f0=initial()
i=0;
L=ALICE[ALICE[0](23,10,5)]      #A_1,...,A_5
(a0,b0,c0)=L[i]:
M=CHRIS[CHRIS[0](a0,b0,c0)] #C(A_1)_j
j=0
for a1,b1,c1 in M:
     j=j+1
     P=ALICE[ALICE[0](a1,b1,c1)]
     print("A(C_"+str(i+1)+")_"+str(j)+"): "+str(P)+". Empty intersection: "+str(bool(~any(P))))
```

Comment: I think my comment above was miss-understood. There is indeed at least one such set, but there are more than one ("in fact I find many such $A(C(Ai)j)$
"). So I do not think the statement is false for every i≠i∗. Moreover, even looking at the first one I found $(A(C(A3)2)=[(26,23,13),(46,13,13)])$, this candidate doesn't have an intersection with the correct solution. So, it is not totally clear (to me, at least yet) how Alice goes from identifying candidates to knowing numbers.

Comment: By "nonempty intersection" I do not mean that they intersect with the solution list, but rather *with each other*.  If $A(C(A_3)_2)$ was actually Alice's list, then *she would have known that the number $13$ was part of the solution*.  Thus Chris cannot have the list $C(A_3)$ (because if he did have that list, he could not have been certain that Alice did not know any of the numbers), and so Alice can rule out $A_3$.

Comment: Ok, sorry for having miss-understood your explanation. Please give me the time to compute (and read better).

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm finding it difficult to explain in a way which is both rigorous and illuminating.  Too much "Alice thought that Chris thought..."

Comment: Indeed I see your explanation is correct. Can I edit your answer to add the numbers/code to confirm it? It might making it easier to understand in the future if the reasoning is illustrated.

Comment: Sure, feel free to edit